# problem with dynamic field elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, packetbeat

i am running Packet-beat in my server.

i'm disabled dynamic field in index mapping . it mean if new data coming . don't create new fields.

in my mapping there is not extra field but when i send a request from postman for show records . there is a new field in my result but i'm sure its not in my mapping.

how is possible?

Comment: When [A] the mapping for a specific field is not defined and [B] the dynamic fields are disabled, you shouldn't be able to index documents with new fields at all. Validate whether you have really disabled the dynamic fields or not!

Comment: @vishwarajanand yes . im disabled dynmaic field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm founding the answer.

in `elasticsearch` when set `dynamic:false` its mean:

> The dynamic setting controls whether new fields can be added dynamically or not. It accepts three settings:
>
> true : Newly detected fields are added to the mapping. (default)
>
> false : Newly detected fields are ignored. These fields will not be indexed so will not be searchable but will still appear in the _source field of returned hits. These fields will not be added to the mapping, new fields must be added explicitly.
>
> strict : If new fields are detected, an exception is thrown and the document is rejected. New fields must be explicitly added to the mapping.

extra description in this [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic.html)